# How does SE determine the CSS and JS version parameter?

Tags: discussion, design, javascript

According to the source, the JS and CSS files I'm loading are:

```
stub.js?v=e922af98260a
all.css?v=b7ced9688c61
```

Just wondering how those "v" parameters are generated. On my websites I generally just use an integer which I manually increment, so I'm curious if these are generated automatically somehow.

Comment: Don't know, but they're probably hashed for build updates.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
[balpha@localhost ~]$ curl -s http://meta.stackoverflow.com | grep stub.js
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/content/js/stub.js?v=e922af98260a"></script>
stub.js?v=e922af98260a
[balpha@localhost ~]$ curl -s http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/js/stub.js | sha1sum
e922af98260a8e3c3e499cb81e5ebab95c9ac   -
[balpha@localhost ~]$
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Followup question - how do you insert the SHA1 prefix into (presumably) the ASP.NET MVC app?

Comment: @Jon: The app has access to a local copy of the file (even if it's eventually served from the CDN), so it can just read the file once at startup, build the checksum, and then cache it.